# Lookup - like Enum but Guid based, but still with intellisense convenience / safety / readability

Tags: c#

I use Enums for looking up values that rarely change in a database - eg:

```
public enum CarTypes
{
    Sedan,
    HatchBack,
    Saloon,
    SportsCar
}
```

To access a car type:

```
CarTypes.Sedan
```

This is great as it gives me intellisense of every option when I press '.' - and the int ID can be mirrored in a database table (an ID of 0 in this case).

However, if I need to mirror a rarely changing database table that has Guid IDs - and I still want the intellisense convenience, safety and readability of being presented with all possibilities after pressing '.' - what are my options?

I've tried to find something like this in Bing - but every option uses string values - so lacks the '.' intellisense advantages (eg List, Dictionary etc).

How can I do this in a best practice way?

Comment: The only option would be to have a static class full of static readonly/const fields

Comment: Create a static class `CarTypes`. Within, create public static readonly fields for each GUID value/constant you need.

Comment: That's what I was thinking - is that 'best practice' - any problems with that? Thoughts? Am I wrong to want to do this? It seems like it has many advantages, no?

Comment: Not really a problem, except if you want to serialize in some human-readable format (say JSON), and want to have the "Enum" values serialized by name and not by value. But then again, that would normally just be a "cosmetic problem".

Comment: However, capable serialization packages (such as Json.NET, for example) provide a high degree of customizability (to a point of allowing generation of specification-breaking Json), possibly making this a non-issue. So, whether such is a problem or not thus also would depend on the capabilities of the serialization engine...

Comment: Good point but yeah I don't need to do that. The advantage of doing this is it also stops typos in string values

Comment: `However, if I need to mirror a rarely changing database table that has Guid IDs` Consider adding a new UNIQUE (int) column to the database table that can be used for lookup. And then use an enum.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could just create static properties of whatever type you want (Guid, string, etc). The downside of this is then all APIs revolve around whatever underlying type you choose to represent these objects as and while this can be easy to implement it has several drawbacks. It can be more difficult to debug with opaque types like Guid. The caller needs to remember where the given constants are (probably in some helper class) and it can be confusing when there are multiple sets of these constants which can be interchanged by accident because they use the same underlying type. If other information needs to be attached to these types it often has to be done via some helper method that looks up the associated data.

A design that gets around many of these downsides is not that difficult to implement though. Create a class with a private constructor and some static fields/properties that represent the objects you want.

```
class CarTypes
{
    private CarTypes(Guid id) 
    {
        Id = id;
    }

    public static CarTypes Sedan { get; } = new CarTypes(Guid.Parse("6f8bdca0-2fb3-4163-884b-b75b1d20a428"));

    public static CarTypes HatchBack { get; } = new CarTypes(Guid.Parse("4ad6432a-ed9d-4947-91a6-78756df51a81"));

    public Guid Id { get; }
}
```

You could also add a Name and/or an overload for ToString which would be more convenient for debugging.

If you need to go from Guids or strings to CarTypes that's a little more work, but you can easily use reflection to build a lookup that does this for a Parse method.

The benefit of this sort of design is that you can write your API around objects in the domain of your program (e.g. CarTypes) and you have more options open to you in the future to evolve the API. If you need to add more data properties or even behavior in methods you are able to do that.